# Ambiguity in Ruby class name resolution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently did some code refactoring in a Rails codebase in which I converted some code that defined some classes like this (class bodies elided):

`foo/user_bar.rb`:

```
module Foo
  class UserBar; end
end
```

`foo/sub_user_bar.rb`:

```
module Foo
  class SubUserBar < UserBar; end
end
```

...to:

In `foo/bar/user.rb`:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class User; end
  end
end
```

In `foo/bar/sub_user.rb`:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class SubUser < User; end
  end
end
```

This introduced a subtle problem in that there was already an existing top-level class called `User` (a Rails model), and `SubUser` was being derived from that, not from `User` in the same module.  I'm guess that this is because the order that Rails loads classes is unpredictable...?

Anyway, I found that I could disambiguate by declaring the `SubUser` class like this:

```
class SubUser < self::User
```

...which seems to work, although I couldn't find any examples of it in a modest amount of searching.  It does look a little weird, though.  And now I'm concerned that I really ought to be doing this for every class in my module, just in case a top-level class with the same name is ever introduced.

There are two styles of in-module class declarations throughout my company's codebase:

```
class A::B::Foo; end
```

And:

```
module A; module B; class Foo; end; end; end
```

I've always preferred the latter method since it allows for access to other names in the module without fully-qualified names, but now I've found that there's potentially a trap when I use it.  So what's the best practice here?

- Don't declare classes within a `module`; always use fully qualified names (`class A::B::C::Foo < A::B::C::Bar`)
- Declare classes in a `module` but always fully qualify superclass names (`module A; module B; module C; class Foo < A::B::C::Bar`)
- Declare classes in a `module` and use unqualified names but always use `self::` when extending a class in the same module
- Declare classes in a `module` and use unqualified names but stay aware of possible name collisions in the top-level namespace (seems risky)

Or do Ruby and/or Rails offer some other, cleaner way to resolve the issue?

Comment: note that the rubystyle.guide prefers to ["Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit nesting"](https://rubystyle.guide/#namespace-definition) (see definition for reasoning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally where there's ambiguity you specify full namespace paths:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class SubUser < Foo::Bar::User; end
  end
end
```

That might seem verbose, but it's also specific and unambiguous.

Where you want to refer to literal top-level `User` you'd specify `::User`.

Answer (score 3):

Modules are identified by constants.<sup>1</sup> The resolution of module look-ups is therefore determined by the procedure for looking up constant references. According to "The Ruby Programming Language", by David Flanagan and Yukihero Matsumoto, 1st Ed. 2008 (p. 261-262), constant look-ups are performed in the following order, where `mod` is the innermost module that encloses the reference to the constant:

- `mod`.
- the next enclosing module, continuing until there are no more enclosing modules. (Top-level/global constants are not considered at this step). The class method [Module::nesting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-c-nesting) returns an array of modules that are so searched, in the order in which they are searched.
- the elements of `mod.ancestors`, in index order (i.e., the inheritance hierarchy).
- top-level constant definitions.
- the value returned by the method [Module#const_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-const_missing), with `mod` being the receiver and the constant expressed as a symbol being the argument, provided the method has been defined.

Let's see what we may learn by inserting `puts Module.nesting.inspect` and `puts ancestors` statements into the code.

```
module Foo
  class UserBar
    puts "nesting for UserBar=#{Module.nesting.inspect}"
    puts "#{self}.ancestors=#{ancestors}"
  end
end
  # nesting for UserBar=[Foo::UserBar, Foo]
  # Foo::UserBar.ancestors=[Foo::UserBar, Object, Kernel,
  #   BasicObject]

module Foo
  class SubUserBar < UserBar
    puts "nesting for SubUserBar=#{Module.nesting.inspect}"
    puts "#{self}.ancestors=#{ancestors}"
  end
end
  # nesting for SubUserBar=[Foo::SubUserBar, Foo]
  # Foo::SubUserBar.ancestors=[Foo::SubUserBar,
  #   Foo::UserBar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class User
      puts "nesting for User=#{Module.nesting.inspect}"
      puts "#{self}.ancestors=#{ancestors}"
    end
  end
end
  # nesting for User=[Foo::Bar::User, Foo::Bar, Foo]
  # Foo::Bar::User.ancestors=[Foo::Bar::User, Object, Kernel,
  #   BasicObject]

module Foo
  module Bar
    class SubUser < User
      puts "nesting for SubBar=#{Module.nesting.inspect}"
      puts "#{self}.ancestors=#{ancestors}"
    end
  end
end
  # nesting for SubBar=[Foo::Bar::SubUser, Foo::Bar, Foo]
  # Foo::Bar::SubUser.ancestors=[Foo::Bar::SubUser,
  #   Foo::Bar::User, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

This tells us that if there is a class `User` that is not contained within `Foo` (as in Rails), that class would the subject of references to `User` in the classes `Foo::UserBar` and `Foo::SubUserBar`, but not in `Foo::Bar::User` or `Foo::Bar::SubUser`. This understanding should help in organising modules to avoid namespace problems.

<sup>1 As classes are modules, whenever I reference "module" below I am referring to classes as well as modules that are not classes.</sup>